# how to add a double thumbed slider in iOS? and why this double slider library no longer works in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uislider

I have an app that has a double slider, the project works fine in swift 1.2 / XCode 6, the plugin I use is [UIXRangeSlider](https://github.com/gumbright/UIXRangeSlider/blob/master/UIXRangeSlider/UIXRangeSlider.swift)

but the problem is it shows weird errors when using in Swift 2 / XCode 7.2

[image]

I tried fixing the errors but they puzzle me, I tried adding `override` and removing it, with no chance, how to fix these errors? or do you know any good alternative?

### EDIT

fixed some errors, I just need help with this please

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with the code you've linked to:

1. `NSCoding`'s `init(coder: NSCoder)` is a failable initializer, so this needs to also be a failable initializer:

   ```
   required init?(coder: NSCoder)
   {
       super.init(coder: coder)
       self.commonInit()
   }
   ```
2. The methods `setInactiveBarImage`, `setActiveBarImage`, `setRightThumbImage`, `setMiddleThumbImage`, and `setLeftThumbImage` conflict with the property setters for the identically named variables in the class (e.g `middleThumbImage`). The compiler generates methods with a signature matching `setVariable:` for use in Objective-C. The best way to solve this is to move the method bodies into `didSet` handlers for each variable, e.g:

   ```
   var activeBarImage:UIImage = UIImage() {
       didSet {
           self.activeBarView.removeFromSuperview()
           self.activeBarView = UIImageView(image: self.activeBarImage)
           self.activeBarView.userInteractionEnabled = false
           self.addSubview(self.activeBarView)
           self.orderSubviews()
           self.setNeedsLayout()
       }
   }
   ```
3. The touch tracking methods are written incorrectly. The superclass interface accepts `UITouch?` and `UIEvent?` - note that both arguments are optionals. To fix the error, change the arguments and handle the optionals:

   ```
   override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
   {
       guard let location = touch?.locationInView(self) else { return false }

       previousLocation = location

       // Hit test the thumb layers
       if leftThumbView.frame.contains(previousLocation)
       {
           trackedElement = .LeftThumb
       }
       else if rightThumbView.frame.contains(previousLocation)
       {
           trackedElement = .RightThumb
       }
       else if middleThumbView.frame.contains(previousLocation)
       {
           trackedElement = .MiddleThumb
       }

       return trackedElement != .None
   }

   override func continueTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
   {
       guard let location = touch?.locationInView(self) else { return false }

       // 1. Determine by how much the user has dragged
       let deltaLocation = Double(location.x - previousLocation.x)
       let deltaValue = (Double(maximumValue) - Double(minimumValue)) * deltaLocation / Double(bounds.width /*- thumbWidth*/)

       switch trackedElement
       {
       case .LeftThumb:
           handleLeftThumbMove(location, delta: deltaValue)
       case .MiddleThumb:
           handleMiddleThumbMove(location, delta: deltaValue)
       case .RightThumb:
           handleRightThumbMove(location, delta: deltaValue)
       default:
           break
       }

       previousLocation = location

       return true
   }

   override func endTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch?, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
   {
       trackedElement = .None
   }
   ```

Hope this fixes the problem!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I just solved the code a few minutes a go by extinct, I just saw your answer, thanks it's really valuable, now it's time to ask the UIXSlider developer for a pull request so they update the custom controller, or maybe i just fork it so people have use of it, Thanks a lot Ryan Davies.

Comment: No problem! I'm sure the author would appreciate a pull request. :-)